# jQuery add variable to Parameters of function

Tags: jquery

Beginners question about adding variables from a split result to a function.
I have split[1] which contains the number for the accordion to be active.

this is the function:

```
jQuery("#termine").accordion({ autoHeight: false, 
                               active: 1, 
                               header: '> div.termin-item > div.termin-header'  
                             });
```

Here I would like to replace the active: "1" with the variable split[1]
any hints on how to add that variable to that list of parameters?

Comment: Sure - just put `split[1]` instead of `1` - on second thoughts, it may need to be an int - `parseInt(split[1], 10)`

Comment: Thanks Archer! you are right - it worked! it was an int...

Comment: No worries - I'll put it as an answer so you can mark it resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this...

```
jQuery("#termine").accordion({
    autoHeight: false, 
    active: parseInt(split[1], 10),
    header: '> div.termin-item > div.termin-header'  
});
```

It converts the string value `split[1]` into an int and passes it as the `active` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
jQuery("#termine").accordion({ 
    autoHeight: false, 
    active: split[1], 
    header: '> div.termin-item > div.termin-header'  
});
```

Comment: thanks for that - but Archer got it right. i had tried this - but the problem is that the return value is most likely an int!

Comment: Jolly good. That's probably better than my solution for parsing ints (split[1]*1).